# How to set rust-analyzer.linkedProjects with eglot?

Tags: directory-local-variables, eglot, rust

My project structure is like this:

```
-- Project Root
  - .git
  - rusttools
    - Cargo.toml
    - src
      - main.rs
```

When I open `main.rs` in Emacs, `eglot` complains:

```
[eglot] Server reports (type=1): Failed to discover workspace.
Consider adding the `Cargo.toml` of the workspace to the [`linkedProjects`](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/manual.html#rust-analyzer.linkedProjects) setti\
ng.
```

And `eglot` doesn't work at all.

I tried to add this in my `.dir-locals.el`:

```
((rust-mode
  .  ((eglot-workspace-configuration
      . (:rust-analyzer (:linkedProjects ["Path/To/Project Root/rusttools/Cargo.toml"]))
      ))
))
```

However it didn't work.

It seems to have *something* do to with git and projectile. I know it doesn't make sense, but when I put a `Cargo.toml` as a sibling to `.git` and specify `workspace` there, it works. However it's not what I want. I'd like to specify `rusttools/Cargo.toml` as my project workspace directly.

Answer (score 0):

I kinda got it. This is a misled question, since the problem isn't `linkedProjects` isn't set, but `eglot` using `project.el` to find the project root.

Discussion: https://github.com/joaotavora/eglot/discussions/687